# Cartesian coordinates to LatLng in LeafletJS

Tags: leaflet

I am getting x,y (cartesian) coordinates for a map from an API. I "draw" this map using `polylines`, it looks like this:

[image]

Problem is: due to the projection, the hallways in the south are a lot wider than in reality. I tried converting the coordinates to `LatLng` with `LayerPointToLatLng`, but no luck. How do I properly convert cartesian coordinates to LatLng so that the distortion is compensated? Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at Leaflet `L.CRS.Simple` and the corresponding tutorial on Leaflet website?

Comment: I have not, but I will now! Thanks. Will let you know if it's an appropriate solution.

Comment: @ghybs Well, that was easy. I changed the CRS to simple and now it works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot, I should have checked that tutorial more throughly before.

Comment: That's what I created my application with. Not sure if it's relevant, but I added it nevertheless.